# QGIS how to use the NNJoin Plugin algorithm within a Python script?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I have two layers: 1 point layer and 1 line layer. My goal is to calculate the nearest line to every point and I am doing this with the NNJoin Plugin. Now I want to do the same within a Python script, but I do not know how to access the NNJoin-Algorithm from here.

If this is not possible, are there any alternatives?

I have already read through the duplicate question but it doesn't quite answer my question.